# Eigenvalues problem 1

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> For an $n\times n$ matrix $A,$ if $$\det(A-\lambda I)=(\lambda_1 -\lambda)(\lambda_2-\lambda)\cdots(\lambda_n-\lambda)=0,$$ 
>   holds then we have
>   $$
> \begin {align*}
> (\lambda_1 I-A)(\lambda_2 I-A)\cdots (\lambda_n I -A)=0
> \end{align*}
> $$

Since $Tr(A) = \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k$ and $\det(A) = \prod _{k=1}^n \lambda_k,$

I checked the case at n=2.

However, in general for $n,$ I don't know how to prove that.

Any help is appreciated!!

Thank you.

Comment: Use Cayley Hamilton.

Comment: Or simply just diagonalize.

Comment: How to know A's diagonalization??

Comment: Are the eigenvalues distinct?

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to use a more descriptive title?

Answer (score 1):

We can construct a set of basis in the $n$-dimensional vector space using the eigenvectors of matrix $A$.  So any vector can be written as $$x = \sum_{i=1}^n x_iv_i,$$ where ${v_i}$ are the eigenvectors of $A$. Note that $$(\lambda_jI-A)v_j = 0 \quad \forall j,$$ then for any vector $x$, $$\begin{split}
  & (\lambda_1 I-A)(\lambda_2 I-A)\cdots (\lambda_n I -A)x \\
= & (\lambda_1 I-A)(\lambda_2 I-A)\cdots (\lambda_n I -A)\sum_{i=1}^nx_iv_i \\
= & (\lambda_1 I-A)(\lambda_2 I-A)\cdots (\lambda_{n-1} I -A)\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_iv_i \\
= & \ldots \\
= & 0.
\end{split}$$
This means matrix $(\lambda_1 I-A)(\lambda_2 I-A)\cdots (\lambda_n I -A)$ equals to 0.

---

For defective matrix which its eigenvectors doesn't span the whole space, we need to use the generalized eigenvectors. For eigenvalue $\lambda$ of matrix $A$ with $m$ multiplicity, it has $m$ linearly independent general eigenvectors $u_k$ satisfying $$(\lambda I-A)^mu_k = 0.$$
A complete basis of $n$ dimensional space can be formed with the set of regular eigenvectors and generalized eigenvectors. Also note that $(\lambda_iI-A)(\lambda_jI-A) = (\lambda_jI-A)(\lambda_iI-A)$, we can always arrange so the factors $(\lambda I-A)$ corresponding to multiple roots stay together.  The logic of the original proof still works.

Comment: Why does the matrix have an eigenbasis?

Comment: you should add that you assume (wasn't included in the question) that the $n-$ eigenvalues are pairwise distinct and hence the vector space indeed has a basis of eigenvectors

Comment: @MichaelBurr Good point. Let me think how to address that.

Comment: You can use a basis of generalized eigenvectors.

Comment: Precisely.  Thanks for forcing me think more!

Comment: The statement of the nonvanishing of the generalized eigenvectors is not always the situation encountered with generalized eigenvectors.  Usually, there is a chain of generalized eigenvectors $u_{k,j}$ so that $(\lambda I-A)^iu_{k,j}\not=0$ for $i<j$.  However, by adding two generalized eigenvectors together, you can make the case you describe.